# Configuring Sonar Qube and Sonar Scanner for code analysis

Tags: sonarqube, code-analysis, sonar-runner

We will be using sonarqube for code analysis and reviews .

How get my Visual Studio projects visible on sonar dashboard ?

Any leads regarding same will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. You might want to take a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You've asked 3 questions here (you even numbered them, very helpfully). But this site has a one-question-one-post format. I suggest you edit your post to your first, most important question and follow up with others as needed.

Comment: Thanks G.Ann for referring me the much needed 'How do I ask a good question' guide.

Answer (score 0):

To get your projects into SonarQube, you'll need to *analyze* them.

Since you're dealing with Visual Studio projects, take a look at the [SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) (once you've [set up your SonarQube instance](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Setup+and+Upgrade), that is).

Comment: And Sonar Scanner is a must to Analyze ?

Comment: Yes, it is :-).

Comment: GoodDay,I was installing SonarScanner as per https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner link . Step 3 is 'Add the <install_directory>/bin directory to your path.' Is it suggesting to add SonarScanner directory within Sonarqube folder or something else ?

Comment: The assumption is that you're analyzing on a different machine than is hosting your SonarQube instance, which is why that's not addressed in the docs. Install the scanner outside the SQ directory.

Comment: Hi Ann, I have installed Sonar Scanner and Sonar Qube and i am running code analysis with Sonar Scanner and i can see the results on Sonar Qube server in bowser. Also,I have SonarLint added in my VS2015 and i am using connected mode with my sonar qube server. And i run analysis with sonar lint also locally.The question i have is can i run analysis with sonarlint and see the same on sonarqube server without involving sonar scanner at all?

Comment: That's a totally different question @RehanHaque. I suggest you post it as one.